# В чём различия резервирования памяти

Tags: winapi, ассемблер, память, memory

Всем привет, меня достаёт один вопрос, в чём различия резервирования памяти, вот в пример привожу два варианта...

### 1) GLOBAL:

```
  invoke GlobalAlloc, GHND, 500
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*(Кстати выделенная память почему то не зануляется)*

### 2) HEAP:

Либо вот так...

```
  invoke HeapCreate, 0, 0, 500
  invoke HeapAlloc, eax, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, 500
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какая разница этих способов, если можно поподробнее?

Comment: `GlobalAlloc` — это пережиток времён 16-битной Windows. Вполне возможно, что сейчас это просто тонкая обёртка над `HeapAlloc`.

Comment: @insolor оформите комментарий как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрим документацию:

### [GlobalAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366574(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Allocates the specified number of bytes from the heap.
>
> > **Note**  The global functions have greater overhead and provide fewer
> >     features than other memory management functions. New applications
> >     should use the [heap functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366711(v=vs.85).aspx) unless documentation states that a
> >     global function should be used. For more information, see [Global and Local Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366596(v=vs.85).aspx).

Т.е. память выделяется из кучи, но вместо этой функции рекомендуется использовать функции работы с кучей (`HeapAlloc` в том числе).

*(по поводу зануления - по той же ссылке можно увидеть, что есть специальный флаг `GMEM_ZEROINIT` для этого)*

### [HeapAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Allocates a block of memory from a heap. The allocated memory is not movable.

Тут все понятно.

Еще, к прочтению: [**Memory Management Functions - Global and Local Functions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366781(v=vs.85).aspx#global_and_local_functions)

> The following are the global and local functions. These functions are
>   provided for compatibility with 16-bit Windows and are used with
>   Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE), the clipboard functions, and OLE data
>   objects. Unless documentation specifically states that a global or
>   local function should be used, new applications should use the
>   corresponding [heap function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366711(v=vs.85).aspx) with the handle returned by
>   [**GetProcessHeap**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366569(v=vs.85).aspx). For equivalent functionality to the global or local
>   function, set the heap function's dwFlags parameter to 0.

Т.е. данные функции оставлены только для совместимости с 16-битными приложениями, и используются с DDE, функциями работы с буфером обмена и OLE объектами. Когда документация по WinAPI функции явно не говорит, что нужно использовать например `GlobalAlloc`, рекомендуется использовать соответствующие Heap-функции (и ниже в тексте таблица соответствия Global/Local и Heap функций).

По поводу приведенных в вопросе дампов. Просто глядя на дамп (содержимое памяти по адресу) вы не поймете разницу в работе функций (кроме разве что обнуления памяти). Лучше сразу смотреть документацию, а не гадать по дампам.